# phpMyAdmin freezes when running any query

Tags: mysql, macos, phpmyadmin, macos-sierra

I have a new MacBook Pro and have installed/configured development environment to include PHP and MySql in particular. MySql Workbench works 100% and I can run queries from terminal (i.e., the command line). However, every SQL query I run in phpMyAdmin simply freezes. No matter how simple the query. The exact same query runs fine in MySql Workbench, but I much prefer phpMyAdmin.

I've followed this and reinstalled mysql and phpMyAdmin twice. 
https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-macos-sierra/

I suspect there is a permission setting somewhere.

What am I doing wrong? Why would phpMyAdmin work, but not execute queries?

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am facing the same problem in High sierra. Did you find any solution for that. I have followed same url for installing mysql

Comment: me too, got same issue. Hopefully someone cant fix it

Comment: Same problem still exists PMA version 4.7.9. Mysql version 5.7.20. PHP version 5.6.31. Mac OS high sierra 10.13.3.

Comment: Given that there have been no answers to this yet, I went ahead and submitted an issue with the phpMyAdmin github team and hopefully that will result in someone getting to the bottom of this: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/14089.